# Factorization with smart way.

Tags: prime-factorization

$3^{15} + 1 = 14348908$
How to factorize it without using calculator. Please me give. 
I can only do:

$3^{15} + 1 = 14348908 = (3+1)(3^{14}-...+ 1)$

Comment: $3$ and $5$ are also divisors of $15$.

Comment: Do you mean factorize it *completely*, down to a product of primes?

Answer (score 2):

Other divisors of $3^{15}+1$ are $3^5+1$ and $3^3+1$. And both are divisible by $3+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from ajotatxe's answer, we know that $3^{15}+1$ is divisible by $3+1=4$, $3^3+1=28=4\cdot7$, and $3^5+1=244=4\cdot61$.  If you remember how to do long division, it's relatively easy to do the following by hand:

$$\begin{align}
14348908/4&=3587227\\
3587227/7&=512461\\
512461/61&=8401
\end{align}$$

So so far we have

$$3^{15}+1=4\cdot7\cdot61\cdot8401$$

It remains to factor the $8401$ or show that it's prime.  At this point I think you're out of luck, and just have to do trial division by primes up to something shy of $100$.  You can pretty easily see that $3$, $5$, $7$, and $11$ don't divide $8401$, but after that I think there's a lot of scratchwork to do, unless (like me) you peak at the answer online.